# Typescript partial type inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am stumped by this and cannot figure out how to do this without a second function:

```js
interface Fixed { a: number }
const fn = <A, B extends {} = {}>(b: B) => {
  return b
}

fn({ a: 1 }) // { a: number }
fn<Fixed>({ a: 1 }) // {}

const fn2 = <A>() => <B extends {} = {}>(b: B) => {
  return b
}

const result = fn2<Fixed>()({ a: 1 }) // { a: number }
```

Why does Typescript not infer the type of B if I fix type A?
If I return a function that in turn tries to infer the type of B everything works again.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? You have a lot of declared but unused type parameters

Comment: If you specify one parameter the other will not be inferred (the default will always be used). There is no partial inference support (some was planned never happened). The two function solution you found is the way to go.

Comment: @Aron: There is more code to it, I just liked to know why I could not let one part of the generic types be inferred without stacking two functions.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thank you, in the answer below was a nice github issue exactly discussing my problems with this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Type inference works based on an *all or nothing* principle. In the first case:

```js
fn({ a: 1 })
```

has no generic type parameters provided so it will infer both:

- `B` will be inferred as `{ a: number }` based on the function argument;
- and `A` will be inferred as `unknown` since it's not used anywhere in the function.

In the second case:

```js
fn<Fixed>({ a: 1 })
```

you have specified one of the generic types and that unfortunately means that **type inference will not be used for the rest of the type parameters** – therefore:

- `A` is specified as `Fixed`;
- `B` is not given so instead of inferring it it will default to `{}`.

As annoying as this is, it is just how TypeScript works. Your second example with two function calls is the usual workaround to this issue.

Related [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, I did not find that issue during my search. I'd love to get this changed, in my mind I still think that typescript should easily do this... But here we go stacking functions again.

Comment: any workaround with a single function call?

Comment: None that I know of unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

I believe currying is the solution. Just a general example:

```js
const x = <I>(v: I) => <O>((v: I) => O) => O

// fully typed
x<number>(10)<string>((n) => `${n * 2}`);

// partial inference NO.1
x(10)<string>((n) => `${n * 2}`);

// partial inference NO.2
x<number>(10)((n) => `${n * 2}`);

// full inference
x(10)((n) => `${n * 2}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to pass a second argument just for type inference. The trick is to cast `{}` to the desired value:

```
interface Fixed { a: number }
const fn = <A, B extends {} = {}>(b: B, _param_just_for_type_inference: A) => {
  return b
}

fn({ a: 1 }, {} as Fixed)
/*
const fn: <Fixed, {
    a: number;
}>(b: {
    a: number;
}, _param_just_for_type_inference: Fixed) => {
    a: number;
}
*/
```