# Optional generic in React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two problems with the following code.

```
interface MyForm {
  age: number;
  email: string;
  name: string;
}

function Form<
  T,
  ComponentProps extends {
    name: string;
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent) => void;
  }
>(
  props: {
    component:
      | React.ComponentClass<ComponentProps>
      | React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>;
    name: keyof T;
  } & Omit<ComponentProps, "name" | "onChange">
) {
  const { component: Component, name, ...rest } = props;

  const handleChange = () => {
    //
  };

  return <Component {...(rest as any)} name={name} onChange={handleChange} />;
}

function Component(props: {
  name: string;
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent) => void;
  color: "blue" | "yellow";
}) {
  const { color, name, onChange } = props;
  return <input name={name} onChange={onChange} style={{color}} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* in this code, the name is not checked */}
      <Form color="blue" component={Component} name="something" />
      {/* in this code, the name is checked, but I must define all generics */}
      <Form<MyForm, React.ComponentProps<typeof Component>>
        color="yellow"
        component={Component}
        name="name"
      />
      {/* this doesn't work */}
      <Form<MyForm> color="blue" component={Component} name="email" />
    </>
  );
}
```

At first, I would like to call the Form component like this `<Form<MyForm> color="blue" component={Component} name="email" />` instead of defining the second generic. In a complex component I have more properties and more generics and I don't want to enforce other programmers to define all generic only because I want that the `name` must match the keys in `MyForm`. And that's the goal, that the `name` must be checked by TypeScript and must be keyof `MyForm`. I know I can use optional generic and define the default type, but it breaks the logic and then I cannot pass `color` when calling `Form`. And I cannot define that the color is required, because the logic is, that the `component` must have `name` and `onChange` property and I don't care about the rest and just pass the rest to the component.

At second, I cannot get rid of the any in `{...(rest as any)}`. I don't know, why I am getting an error when I use only `{...rest}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you are asking for in your first question is to have the user of your `<Form>` component to be able to specify *some* generic parameters, (e.g. `<Form<MyFormInterface> />`, and have typescript still infer the rest of them (e.g. the props of the component passed to the `component` property).

Unfortunately, this is not supported at the moment - type inference is an all-or-nothing proposition - either typescript infers everything, or the user specifies everything. There is [an extremely popular github issue asking for this exact feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678777/4739687) for a more generic explanation.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way just define and export function overloads

```
export function a<A>(value: A, value2: string) :void
export function a<A,T>(value: A, value2:T) : void
export function a<A,T>(value: A, value2:T) {
  console.log(value, value2)
}
//throw error
a<string>("", 3)
//good
a<string>("","")
//throw error
a<string, number>("","")
//good
a<string, number>("",2)
```