# Typescript working with generics and building an object from a class

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to be able to build a function/method to build an option from an array.  For instance, I am using Mikro-ORM, and there is an type call `FindOptions<T>` which I can populate with my database sort order request.

The FindOptions interface is defined as:

```
export interface FindOptions<T, P extends string = never> {
    populate?: readonly AutoPath<T, P>[] | boolean;
    orderBy?: (QueryOrderMap<T> & {
        0?: never;
    }) | QueryOrderMap<T>[];
    limit?: number;
    offset?: number;
    ...
}
```

When working with the FindOptions directly, I can specify my Entity as the generic `const MikroORMSoryBy: FindOptions<TimeEntryEntity>` which works for code completion and compiler hints, etc.

I can build my sort by doing:

```
const MikroORMSoryBy: FindOptions<TimeEntryEntity> = {
    orderBy: { EntryDate: QueryOrder.ASC, Id: QueryOrder.ASC, UserId: QueryOrder.ASC }
};
```

I can clearly list my fields without an issue. I can even list them as strings, and this works.

```
orderBy: { 'EntryDate': QueryOrder.ASC, 'Id': QueryOrder.ASC, 'UserId': QueryOrder.ASC }
```

My question is, how can I convert this so that I can build the orderBy using code?  For instance, I could pass a string[] of the column names (`['EntryDate', 'Id', 'UserId']`) and loop through this with a forEach or something.

```
const Fields: Array<string> = ['EntryDate', 'Id', 'UserId'];
Fields.forEach( (OneField: string) => {
    ...
});
```

What I do not know how to do though, is build the orderBy, to be built from my string array, instead of having to hard code the names.  This would allow me to build a common function for building a sort option.

Ideally, I want something like:

```
const Fields: Array<string> = ['EntryDate', 'Id', 'UserId'];
Fields.forEach( (OneField: string) => {
    orderBy[OneField] = QueryOption.ASC;  // ???
});
```

Comment: But how do you know how to sort each field? Your last example doesn't have any way of associating each field to ASC or DESC.

Comment: I would change the string for that.  Assume just to set them all to be QueryOption.ASC as that is not the issue I am having, it is building the structure properly.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXjX1m) work for you? You may need to change it a bit because I don't have access to the complete `FindOptions` type.

Comment: It does not compile: TS2559: Type '{ EntryDate: QueryOrder; Id: QueryOrder; UserId: QueryOrder; }' has no properties in common with type FindOptions<TimeEntryEntity, never>'.

Comment: Well yeah that's because you need to set the result to `orderBy`. It doesn't generate all of your find options.

Comment: I think it needs to get added into orderBy{} somehow.

Comment: If you are using the same names as my example, then it would be `{ orderBy: orderBy(...) }`

Comment: Sorry, I realized that when I looked back it.  I did get it to work adding it in as you suggested.  Can you move this to an answer so I can accept it, but also add some detail so  I can follow what you are doing?  I need to do something similar for building other structures from the entities, using either entity data (multiple records) or more fields in arrays, adn want to understand the basics of how this is working so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll start by defining a new function that takes two generic parameters:

```
function buildOrderBy<E, Fields extends (keyof E)[]>(fields: [...Fields]) => {
    return fields.reduce((r, f) => ({ ...r, [f]: QueryOrder.ASC }), {} as { [K in Fields[number]]: QueryOrder });
}
```

Simply put, we take the keys of an entity and construct an object of the keys that map to `QueryOrder.ASC`.

But then if we try to call it here:

```
const orderByBuilder = buildOrderBy<MyEntity>([...]);
```

We'll get an error because we did not provide the `Fields` generic parameter.
If we do, then we essentially just duplicated our input to this function, which is terrible. This is called [partial type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference) (or lack thereof), and one way to get around it is to use currying:

```
function buildOrderBy<E>() {
    return <Fields extends (keyof E)[]>(fields: [...Fields]) => {
        return fields.reduce((r, f) => ({ ...r, [f]: QueryOrder.ASC }), {} as { [K in Fields[number]]: QueryOrder });
    };
}
```

Now we can call it like this:

```
const orderBy = buildOrderBy<MyEntity>()([...]);
```

Which might be more useful since you can store the intermediary function:

```
const orderBy = buildOrderBy<MyEntity>();

orderBy([...]); // use independently
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXjX1m)

Comment: Is there a way to ignore unknown fields (not in entity) instead of it generating an error?  For instance, if the field list had 'ABC' in it, which is not in the entity, skip adding it to the orderBy object, and do not error out?

Comment: @StevenScott It'll look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP9q5w). Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to filter out these keys.

Comment: Thanks.  That is sort of what I was playing around with and getting to.  Maybe I will have to try to handle the dynamic nature with something similar in a try/catch to at least determine the error, and return accordingly.