# TypeScript: typed path to nested property (as tuple)

Tags: typescript, types, nested

I'm learning functional programming and trying to implement `assoc` function (functional setter) as a higher order function with the support of nested properties. I'm okay with the depth being limited by the number of function overloads.

What I'm having now.

The actual implementation:

```js
export type KeyOf<T> = T extends object ? keyof T : never;
export type Setter<S, A> = (whole: S) => (part: A) => S;

export function assoc<T, K1 extends KeyOf<T> = KeyOf<T>>(
  k1: K1
): Setter<T, T[K1]>;

export function assoc<
  T,
  K1 extends KeyOf<T> = KeyOf<T>,
  K2 extends KeyOf<T[K1]> = KeyOf<T[K1]>
>(k1: K1, k2: K2): Setter<T, T[K1][K2]>;

export function assoc<
  T,
  K1 extends KeyOf<T> = KeyOf<T>,
  K2 extends KeyOf<T[K1]> = KeyOf<T[K1]>,
  K3 extends KeyOf<T[K1][K2]> = KeyOf<T[K1][K2]>
>(k1: K1, k2: K2, k3: K3): Setter<T, T[K1][K2][K3]>;

export function assoc<
  T,
  K1 extends KeyOf<T> = KeyOf<T>,
  K2 extends KeyOf<T[K1]> = KeyOf<T[K1]>,
  K3 extends KeyOf<T[K1][K2]> = KeyOf<T[K1][K2]>,
  K4 extends KeyOf<T[K1][K2][K3]> = KeyOf<T[K1][K2][K3]>
>(k1: K1, k2: K2, k3: K3, k4: K4): Setter<T, T[K1][K2][K3][K4]>;

export function assoc(...path: any[]): any {
  return (whole: any) => {
    return (value: any) => {
      return assocDeep(whole, path as any, value);
    };
  };
}
```

But when I use it with three keys (or more), it seems it can't resolve keys deeper than the second level:

```js
import { assoc } from './assoc';

type Company = {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly name: string;
  readonly address: Address;
};

type Address = {
  readonly country: string;
  readonly region: string;
  readonly street: Street;
  readonly building: string;
};

type Street = {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly kind: string;
};

const setStreetName = assoc<Company>('address', 'street', 'name');
                                                          ~~~~~~
```

As result the TypeScript compiler says:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ts(2345)

How can I make it work for more levels of nesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we'll get a list (as a union) of all the possible paths:

```
type PathsOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K] | (T[K] extends object ? [K, ...PathsOf<T[K]>] : never);
}[keyof T];
```

```
export function assoc<T>() {
  return function<P extends PathsOf<T>>(...path: P): MakeSetter<T, P> {
    return null!; // your impl here (might need casting...)
  }
}
```

Then we'll get the paths of whatever was given to `assoc` and use that for our `path` parameter. Note that you have to use currying as [partial type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference) is not available to us.

Here's `MakeSetter`:

```
type MakeSetter<T, P, Original = T> = P extends [infer First extends keyof T, ...infer Rest] ? MakeSetter<T[First], Rest, Original> : Setter<Original, T>;
```

We're just "iterating" over the path and getting the next value, and then when we're done (no more keys), we return our setter.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLyKKW)

Comment: thanks! it works well for many levels, hooray!

Comment: is it possible to avoid separation into two functions? It requires an extra call without arguments...

Comment: @AlexChandler I don't think so, or else we can't give the return type an accurate type. See the linked question "partial type inference".

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time! I'll try to dig deeper into the solution.