# Is it possible to provide generic type args by name?

Tags: typescript, axios

Say there is a generic type defined that provides both named args and default types for the generic args. Like this type from `axios` lib:

```js
post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>
```

I can specify the response type quite easily, since it is the first arg and the other args have defaults:

```js
myClient.post<MyResponseType>(...)
```

I would like to be able to specify the request body type as well, which is the `D` arg to the generic type.

But it's awkward because there is the derived param `R` in the middle... which I never want to manually specify. So I can't do:

```js
myClient.post<MyResponseType, MyRequestType>(...)
```

I'd have to redundantly spell it out like:

```js
myClient.post<MyResponseType, AxiosResponse<MyResponseType>, MyRequestType>(...)
```

...which is long-winded and ugly.

AFAICT there is no shorthand in TS, e.g. I can't do:

```js
myClient.post<MyResponseType, D=MyRequestType>(...)
```

(which seems to beg the question why bother having named generic args)

Is there any trick I could use to annotate my `post` calls with both request and response types in a clean and concise way?

Comment: _"generic type defined that provides both named args and default values for the generic args"_ - I don't think "default values" is the right term to use here: TS is built around _type erasure_, not _reified types_, so while type-parameters have type-arguments, the type-arguments themselves are not "values".

Comment: @Dai I know what you mean -  I'm happy to reword it... "default types" ?  What do TS devs call them?

Comment: I believe "type parameter argument" or "argument for a type-parameter" would be appropriate.

Comment: Anyway, your _overall question_ seems to be "how do I do partial type parameter application in TypeScript" (or "how do I do partial-application of type-parameter arguments in TypeScript") - and yes, that's a mouthful.

Comment: ...which is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference and the answer seems to be "you can't, **but** you can always define your own trivial wrapper function for `<T,D>` that then forwards those type parameters into `<T,AxiosResponse<D>,D>`".

Comment: Uh, I mean `<T,AxiosResponse<T>,D>`, sorry.

Comment: @Dai Thanks, if possible I would like to do it with types only, no runtime stuff i.e. no wrapper function. I don't mind defining some tricky intermediate types

Comment: As a sidebar... would it be better if Axios had just specified their type args in a different order? i.e. if the derived type param `R` was at the end instead of in the middle then I wouldn't have this problem

Comment: I think it should be possible to extend `export class Axios` (looking at Axios' `index.d.ts`) to add a signature-overload to the `post` method. I'm currently _trying_ to do it in the TS Playground.

Comment: _"would it be better if Axios had just specified their type args in a different order?"_ -welllll Axios isn't written in TypeScript, is it? So the `index.d.ts` has to be manually maintained, which means _pain_ for all involved, ugh.

Comment: I got it working, just extend `declare interface Axios {` (_not_ `export class Axios`) in your own code, with this: `post<T,D>(url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
}` - I'll post this as an answer when I get back from dinner in an hour.

Comment: @Anentropic since `D` is accepting `any`, have you considered instead of exposing the Axios instance a wrapper class which would only accept predefined method and endpoint combination statically "knowing" the response type ?

Comment: @Teneff I'm making an api client class which does that, it's in there that I wanted to specify the types more concisely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the current `axios/v1.x/index.d.ts` type defintions](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/2e70cecda42993e1153248f0f96715c3c55f7f39/index.d.ts), you should be able to just extend `export class Axios` in your own `.ts` file to add an overload of `Axios.post` with different type-parameters.

TypeScript, like JavaScript, doesn't support overloaded function implementations, but it does allow for overloaded function signatures, including overloaded generic type parameters.

So the Axios `index.d.ts` has something like this (cut-down for brevity):

```js
export class Axios {
    // ...
    post<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<R>;
    // ...
}
```

TypeScript code that consumes `export class` definitions from a `d.ts` can extend those classes by extending the `class`'s implicit `interface`, so in *your own code*, somewhere near the top of your `.ts` file, you'd simply put *something like this*:

```js
declare interface Axios {
  post<T,D>(url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
}
```

Because the function parameters (`url`, `data`, and `config`) and its `Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>` are all compatible with the underlying implementation *and* don't conflict with the declared `post` function in `index.d.ts` *this is fine*.

...of course, the problem is getting TypeScript to recognize that this `interface Axios` is actually intended to be merged-into-and-extend the `class Axios` from the imported library, rather than being a completely separate `Axios` type. And things get muddied considering how the module system works differently to the old-world global namespace.

So...

#### If you're using `import { Axios } from 'axios'`:

```js
// Step 1. Import Axios:
import { Axios, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

// Step 2. Extend Axios:
declare module 'axios' {
  interface Axios {
    post<T,D>(url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
  }
}

// Step 3. Use Axios:
interface MyRequestDto {
    readonly foobar: string;
}
interface MyResponseDto {
  readonly qux: string;
}

async function foo() {

    const reqDto: MyRequestDto = { foobar: "hmm" };

    const a = new Axios();

    // Look ma! Only two explicit type-parameters!
    const resp = await a.post<MyResponseDto,MyRequestDto>( '/foo', reqDto ); 
    const responseDto: MyResponseDto = resp.data;
    console.log( responseDto.qux );
}
```

#### If you're using non-module, global, or `/// <reference types="axios" />`:

(Disclaimer: I'm not able to provide a complete and working self-contained example because I can't figure out how to get `/// <reference types="" />`-style imports of `index.d.ts` files to work yet, but provided that your code is already currently using Axios just fine then all you need is the `declare interface Axios` part)

```js
// Step 1. Import Axios... somehow:
/// <reference types="axios" />
/// <reference path="axios/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference pleasepleasepleaseworkdamnit="axios" />

// Step 2. Extend Axios:
declare interface Axios {
  post<T,D>(url: string, data?: D, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>;
}

// Step 3. Use Axios:
interface MyRequestDto {
    readonly foobar: string;
}
interface MyResponseDto {
  readonly qux: string;
}

async function foo() {

    const reqDto: MyRequestDto = { foobar: "hmm" };

    const a = new Axios();

    // Look ma! Only two explicit type-parameters!
    const resp = await a.post<MyResponseDto,MyRequestDto>( '/foo', reqDto ); 
    const responseDto: MyResponseDto = resp.data;
    console.log( responseDto.qux );
}
```

Comment: I'm using `import axios from 'axios'` so I have amended the first option to override `AxiosInstance` instead of `Axios`. I also changed the signature to `post<T, D = any>` so I can still use the response-type-only form if needed. But it seems to be working, thanks!