# Typescript wrap function: keep parameters and replace its return type

Tags: typescript, function, wrapper

## What i want to get?

I want to create function `wrap()` which do the following:

```js
const fn = (x: string) => 'some string';

interface CustomObject {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

const wrapped = wrap<CustomObject>(fn);

// typeof wrapped must be: (x: string) => CustomObject
```

## What i tried?

I tried to do this but got two problems.

### First problem

This code does not work properly, because if you start to specify first generic parameter you **MUST** also specify all other not "with-default" generic parameters:

```js
function wrap <Schema, Args extends any[]> (fn: (...args: Args) => any) {
  return (...args: Args): Schema => fn(...args);
}

const myFunction = (bar: string) => 'some string';

const myFunctionWrapper = wrap<{ id: number }>(myFunction);
// -----------------------------------------^: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

### Second problem

If i set default type for second generic parameter, i will lose types of `fn` arguments:

```js
function wrap <Schema, Args extends any[] = any[]> (fn: (...args: Args) => any) {
  return (...args: Args): Schema => fn(...args);
}

const myFunction = (bar: string) => 'some string';

const myFunctionWrapper = wrap<{ id: number }>(myFunction);
// typeof myFunctionWrapper: (...args: any[]) => { id: number } not (bar: string) => { id: number }
```

## Questions.

- What am i doing wrong?
- Is it even possible with TypeScript?

Comment: "Is it even possible with TypeScript?" not really, but perhaps there is an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [partial type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63678777). Alas, this is not available in TS.

A typical workaround is to essentially [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) the generic parameters with a helper function that produces a `wrap` function for each `Schema` type:

```js
function wrapper<Schema>()
{
    return <Args extends any[]>
        (fn: (...args: Args) => any) =>
            wrap<Schema, Args>(fn);
}

function wrap<Schema, Args extends any[]> (fn: (...args: Args) => any)
    : (...args: Args) => Schema
{
    /* magic goes here */
}

const fn = (x: string) => 'some string';

const wrapped = wrapper<CustomObject>()(fn);
// wrapped is (x: string) => CustomObject
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAKAHgLhtATgSzAHMBKZAPhgHIIQBbAUxygOKoG4AoTwqB3OAENgTAMIBXaPQDyAIwBWDYLADenGDHwATbGHF1Z-Lhqj4oAGwbY8hIlwC+3OOLDL84GAHdcggA6-+AB4AZWAACwY6QXJUEk41DQ1cBihxXERAgEFcIggYBnQ+MC08wTAATwBtAF1ydUSG1ARsVAA6dsEciGxs3LIkSjLy-rqGscTvPxDwyMEAGhheiBiEEgcnFzcPSd9piKiFpfzChmLSiprKJrAW9tbO3J6ukZghuIbbjq6nvooYUP2gni9WSqXSaDuDwgLz05nMrzyANmnEcnFAkFgOwCWmQXh8-iCEikdDkimUMRI1zW3AA9DSYFBygEQHA8X5sTA6JJYIYWlhmKxSH8iVAZAolFAgA)

Of course you could store and re-use the intermediate wrapper function:

```
const wrapAsFoo = wrapper<Foo>();

const foo1 = wrapAsFoo((input: string) => 1);
// foo1 is (input: string) => Foo

const foo2 = wrapAsFoo((input: number) => {});
// foo2 is (input: number) => Foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I knew about this solution, but i want to make it work with only one function. It is impossible in TypeScript as i can see in links that you provided...