# TypeScript generics not inferring correctly when specifying one type parameter

Tags: typescript-typings

I have a generic function defined as follows:

```js
function a<T = unknown, K = unknown, Q = unknown, R = unknown>(a: T, b: K, c: R, d: Q) {
  return { a, b, c, d };
}
```

When I call this function without specifying any type parameters, TypeScript correctly infers the types of T, K, Q, and R based on the arguments passed:

```js
a({ a: 2 }, { c: 1, body: 1 }, 1, "2");
// T: { a: number }
// K: { c: number, body: number }
// Q: number
// R: string
```

However, when I specify the type of T, TypeScript seems to lose the type information of the other type parameters:

```js
a<{ a: number }>({ a: 2 }, { c: 1, body: 1 }, 1, "2");
// T: { a: number }
// K: unknown
// Q: unknown
// R: unknown
```

I expect the types of K, Q, and R to be { c: number, body: number }, number, and string, respectively. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @aiden, I think this may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference